# Entries in a bag belonging to the same class or inherited classes

Tags: java

I am unable to complete the source code from the book called Data Structures and Abstractions with Java.

I have included the java files with the question. My error is in OnlineShopper.java.

It says that ArrayBag does not exist and cannot be found.

```
BagInterface<Item> shoppingCart = new ArrayBag<>();
```

Does anyone know what I am missing? Thank you very much for reading this question.

From,
Fred

```
public interface BagInterface<T>
{
    public int getCurrentSize();

    public boolean isEmpty();

    public boolean add(T newEntry);

    public T remove();

    public boolean remove(T anEntry);

    public void clear();

    public int getFrequencyOf(T anEntry);

    public boolean contains(T anEntry);

    public T[] toArray();
}

    /** A class that maintains a shopping cart for an online store.
    @author Frank M. Carrano
    @version 4.0
    */
    public class OnlineShopper
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
             Item[] items = {new Item("Bird feeder", 2050),
                  new Item("Squirrel guard", 1547),
                  new Item("Bird bath", 4499),
                  new Item("Sunflower seeds", 1295)};

             BagInterface<Item> shoppingCart = new ArrayBag<>();
             int totalCost = 0;

             // Statements that add selected items to the shopping cart:
             for (int index = 0; index < items.length; index++)
             {
                 Item nextItem = items[index]; // Simulate getting item from shopper
                 shoppingCart.add(nextItem);
                 totalCost = totalCost + nextItem.getPrice();  
             } // end for

             // Simulate checkout
             while (!shoppingCart.isEmpty())
             System.out.println(shoppingCart.remove());

             System.out.println("Total cost: " + "\t$" + totalCost / 100 + "." +
                     totalCost % 100);
         } // end main
      } // end OnlineShopper
```

Item class:

```
public class Item
{
     private String description;
     private int    price;

     public Item(String productDescription, int productPrice) 
     {
         description = productDescription;
         price = productPrice;
     } // end constructor

     public String getDescription() 
     {
          return description;
     } // end getDescription

     public int getPrice() 
     {
         return price;
     } // end getPrice

     public String toString() 
     {
           return description + "\t$" + price / 100 + "." + price % 100;
     } // end toString
} // end Item
```

Sorry about the misclick

Comment: The code is added now... My apologies that was a bad mistake...

Comment: `ArrayBag` is not a built-in class.

Comment: So does that mean I can create an ArrayBag class?

Say I had a class for ArrayBag why would I create it as ArrayBag<>(); and not just ArrayBag();

Comment: See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: @JacobG. Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `ArrayBag` is not a built-in class and must be created thus.

From the following line of code, we can see it must implement the `BagInterface` interface.

```
BagInterface<Item> shoppingCart = new ArrayBag<>();
```

Both the interface and its implementation should use generics, so the code should look like this.

```
public class ArrayBag<T> implements BagInterface<T>{
   //Here you MUST implement all the methods declared in the interface.
   //Your IDE can help you with that.
}
```

You can have a look at [the tutorial about the generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) mentioned in the comments and [to this one about interfaces](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/interfaces.html).